# Why is my IntelliJ IDEA IDE compiling and running a program, I have already deleted, when I try to compile a new program?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am a beginner in learning JAVA.I tried writing a simple program for printing hello and then modified the program to write an integer along with hello. But, my program on running shows the initial result, i.e. hello, and no integer.I am attaching a screen shot of my screen. I tried deleting that complete file and writing a new one, but still the output comes out to be hello. Please help me understand what is going wrong, and how can i correct it to make my program run properly.

Comment: your bytecode gets run so, you need to build it again and then run it to see the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Build Project, then press Run.
I think problem is that you run previous build.
The file you edit is a .java file. But you run the .class file.
The IDE makes things automatic, so when you press RUN it

1. It compiles .java to .class file
2. RUN the .class file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that it is running the previous build, what you can maybe try to do is save it before running it by pressing(Ctrl+S) or you can run the new project by selecting it and then running it.